# react query useInfiniteQuery typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query

I am using the [pokeApi](https://pokeapi.co/) to fetch data using axios

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchPokemon = async ({
  pageParam = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=0&limit=20"
}) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(pageParam)
    return {results: data.results, nextPage: data.next}
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

useQueryPokemon is a hook that uses [useInfiniteQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useInfiniteQuery) to paginate fetching more pokemon

```
import { useInfiniteQuery } from "react-query";
import { fetchPokemon } from "@api/pokemon";

export const useQueryPokemon = () => {
  return useInfiniteQuery(["pokemon"], fetchPokemon, {
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage?.nextPage,
  });
}
```

I use the `useQueryPokemon` hook in my `index.tsx` to pass `pokemons` props to my `PokemonList`

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { useQueryPokemon } from '@hooks/index';
import PokemonList from '@components/PokemonList';

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const pokemons = useQueryPokemon()

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <PokemonList pokemons={pokemons} />
      </main>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Checking the `pokemons` type, I apply the type to my `PokemonList`

[image]

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { Pokemon } from '@typedef/pokemon';
import { UseInfiniteQueryResult } from "react-query";

const PokemonList = (pokemons: UseInfiniteQueryResult<{
  results: any;
  nextPage: any;
} | undefined, unknown>) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {
          pokemons?.data?.pages.map((group) =>
            group?.results.map((pokemon: Pokemon) => <li key={pokemon.name}>
              <Link href={`/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`} key={pokemon.name}>
                <a>
                  {pokemon.name}
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>)
          )
        }
      </ul>
      <button
        onClick={() => pokemons.fetchNextPage()}
        disabled={!pokemons.hasNextPage || pokemons.isFetchingNextPage}
      >
        {pokemons.isFetchingNextPage
          ? "Loading more..."
          : pokemons.hasNextPage
            ? "Load More"
            : "Nothing more to load"}
      </button>
    </>
  )
}

export default PokemonList
```

But I get the following type error

[image]

> Property 'pokemons' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> UseInfiniteQueryResult<{ results: any; nextPage: any; } | undefined,
> unknown>'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: React function components take objects as their parameters, not multiple arguments. You want `const PokemonList = ({ pokemons: UseInfiniteQueryResult<{...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Andy Ray, The following solves the error

```
const PokemonList = ({
  pokemons
}: {
  pokemons: UseInfiniteQueryResult<{
    results: any;
    nextPage: any;
  } | undefined, unknown>
})
```